# laptop (show applications continiously-left bar) and monitor(auto hide the dock)

Tags: 18.04

I have ubuntu 18.04 in my laptop and I also have a monitor(DELL).I want to show applications in my laptop screen(left bar) -OK  and I also want to auto hide the dock only in my monitor(DELL).Is this possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To change the applications bar, and also hide it (automatically)

- Go to applications / or press super:
- search "settings" → appearance
- Auto-Hide Dock: `[]` ← tick this one.
- And here you can also choose the location of the bar.

Hope this solves your issue!

//Regards

Comment: No,as I said I have one monitor(dell) and a laptop and I want to show applications to laptop screen(This is ok by default) ,but I also want to auto-hide the dock ONLY in monitor(dell) .Thanks for your answer,by the way.

Comment: Oh ;  gosh my bad sorry!  Thanks for pointing those misses out!;  Then;   Maybe dash to dock can be something you're looking for? (Or, gnome-tweaks?)

Comment: @Nick_Gkoutzas Then;   Does this solve your issue? In a terminal:  "gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock isolate-monitors true"

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't solve it.

Comment: Okay :/  Will continue trying;  Hope we fixing it sooner or later;  +Thanks soo much for replying what did work and what didn't; it helps a lot! :)    Reply to your below: comment:  Maybe Maybe not-  But Ill anyways continue trying a bit more at least, :P

Comment: Maybe this regulation can't be done.